# taking common things out in the where condition in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am working on sql server

in my query my where condition is like this:

```
 WHERE   

       ([status] IN (3,4) AND locid = 6 AND dtime >= getdate()-50)
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3
         AND locid = 6 AND dtime >= getdate()-50)
   ORDER BY  
       paydate
```

Instead of this where condition, can I take the common factors out?
Also will that affect anything else in my query? 
Can I get the same result?
If I can take the common factors out, how  can I re-write this?

Comment: Why not write `DelDate >= GetDate() - 3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the common factors out, you have to properly use parentheses to separate your logic. It will not effect the result.

Though the database engines are very smart and most of the time the database engine's query optimizer will optimize this kind of a query for you, my advice to anybody learning sql would be to learn to learn to do it in the right way.

```
WHERE
   ( 
       ([status] IN (3,4))
       OR 
       ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3)
   )
   AND locid = 6 AND dtime >= getdate()-50
```

Comment: sir instead of that code if i added this,,i can get the same result right?

Comment: @user3262364 Yes, the result should be the same.